# Why the generating function of $a_r=r$ is $xf'(x)$ instead of $f'(x)$?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I've seen the following definition:

> > **Theorem 5.1** $f(x),g(x)$ are the generating functions of the sequence $(a_r),(b_r)$.
> >
> > $[...]$
> >
> > $(iv)$ The generating function to $(ra_r)$ is equal to $xf'(x)$, where $f'(x)$ is the derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$.

There is one example of it's usage a little further in the book: To find the generating function to $a_r=r$. The author does the following:

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\ldots$$

Then using $(vi)$:

$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+\ldots\tag{1}$$

And then:

$$xf'(x)=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}=x+2x^2+3x^3+\ldots\tag{2}$$

I don't get why he needed to multiply by $x$ in $(2)$, doesn't $(1)$ already have the coefficients for $a_r=r$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, $(1)$ has the coefficients for $a_r=r+1$. Remember, $a_r$ is the coefficient of $x^r$. Here, for instance, $(1)$ has a constant term of $1$, so the coefficient of $x^0$ is $1$, not $0$, and similarly for every other term.

Comment: Thanks. There's something I'm still on doubt, when I posted the question, I didn't fully understand $(iv)$. Does it mean that to obtain the generating function of an arbitrary sequence, say $a_r=\sin r$, I just need to derive $\sum_k a_k n^k$ and multiply it by $\sin r$?

Comment: @Vÿska: No, it means that if you know that $f(x)=\sum_{r\ge 0}a_rx^r$, then $\sum_{r\ge 0}ra_rx^r=xf\,'(x)$. To put it in different words, if $f(x)$ is the generating function for the sequence $\langle a_r:r\in\Bbb N\rangle$, then $xf\,'(x)$ is the generating function for the sequence $\langle ra_r:r\in\Bbb N\rangle$.

Comment: But then, the $x$ in this case could be other sequences too? Is it possible to make - for example - $2xf'(x)$?

Comment: @Vÿska: That’s the generating function for the sequence $\langle 2ra_r:r\in\Bbb N\rangle$: you’ve just multiplied each coefficient by $2$.

Comment: Oh, good. But does that work for arbitrary sequences? My guess is yes, but I'm really not sure. For example, would it be possible to do as the example I gave earlier [$\sin x f'(x)$]?

Comment: @Vÿska: If $f(x)=\sum_{r\ge 0}a_rx^r$, then $(\sin x)f\,'(x)=\sum_{r\ge 0}a_rx^r\sin x$, which as it stands isn’t a power series at all. Multiplying a power series by $ax^k$ simply shifts the exponent by $k$ and multiplies each coefficient by $a$, so you still have a power series. Differentiating each term also leaves you with a power series. Multiplying by $\sin x$ does not, unless you replace $\sin x$ by its power series and then take the [Cauchy product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) of that with the original power series.

Comment: Got it. Then the only allowable product are the products that leave it as a power series?

Comment: @Vÿska: Yes, if you’re working with generating functions, because the whole point is that the coefficients in the power series represent some sequence. If you don’t have a power series, you’re not representing a sequence in this way.